# gridview creation

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable, viewstate

In asp.net `Grid View`, I want to add rows by entering the values through edit text i.e, with out using database. 
Initially, one empty row will be displayed with "add" button as one column.
When I click "add" button, text boxes will be shown in all columns to enter values and the "add" button field contains "save" and "cancel" button.
When I click "save" the values must be displayed in next row as labels. 

Can any one guide me on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. I would do something like this:

1) Setup your GridView template

2) When a user has filled in the empty text boxes and clicks the "add" button, catch the event, create a new row in a DataTable and store the values

3) Create a new row at position zero and add empty strings

```
table.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
```

4) Databind the DataTable to the GridView

6) Each time a row is added the GridView will grow, just reinsert a blank row (plus your 'add' link) at position zero.

You should probably have a go at it and if you don't achieve the results your looking for post your code. Someone will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the data source to a datatable that you can build up in code with whatever you like.

Here's a link showing how to build a datatable in code...

http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/data-table-csharp.aspx

You would then add rows to the table and set it to the data source for your gridview.

You can also set a gridview's data source with a list:

http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/advanced/ilist-interface-aspnet2-vb.aspx

### Edit 1

Few helpful links

[how to insert data in to grid view using asp.net without database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934065/how-to-insert-data-in-to-grid-view-using-asp-net-without-database)