# How to fetch all values from view state in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am following [how to insert data in to grid view using asp.net without database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934065/how-to-insert-data-in-to-grid-view-using-asp-net-without-database).

Now I have to fetch contents of `viewstate["_data"]` values in loop.

For example firstname, middlename, etc.

Please help me!!!

Comment: Why do you need to store your data in viewstate? Load it from your datasource then use the `GridView` to retain it's data on postback.

Comment: Just improved the formatting But you have to describe the problem you are facing and the steps you have tried as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Expecting `ViewState["_data"]` contains list of fields.

```
 List<fields> data=ViewState["_data"] as List<fields>;
foreach(fields field in data)
{
        var fname=field.firstname;
}
```