# Remove specific Item from view state in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am following [how to insert data in to grid view using asp.net without database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934065/how-to-insert-data-in-to-grid-view-using-asp-net-without-database) tutorial.

But I have used different properties like

```
[Serializable]
public class feilds
{
    public string DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string Document { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileContent { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

I have additional template item in grid

```
      <asp:GridView ID="grdDummy" OnRowCommand=" grdDummy_RowCommand" runat="server">
                  <Columns>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CssClass="colorlnkbtndelete"  CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "DocumentId") %>'><i class="icon-trash"></i></asp:LinkButton>
              </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
              </Columns>      
               </asp:GridView>
```

Now I want that when we click on delete link button, the corresponding item should be deleted from view state and then grid also.

I have tried like below

```
    protected void grdDummy_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            string docid = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            feilds s = new feilds();
            int index = data.FindIndex(s.DocumentId docid);
            data.RemoveAt(index);
            ViewState["_data"] = data;

        }
    }
```

It's not working !!!

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible way :

```
protected void grdDummy_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        string docid = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        //find field by documentId and remove it from list
        data.Remove(data.Find(o => o.DocumentId == docid));

        ViewState["_data"] = data;

        //rebind grid
        grdDummy.DataSource = data;
        grdDummy.DataBind();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Btw, your command argument can be written shorter as :

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DocumentId")%>'
```